# Contacts show gmail contacts instead of phone

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

when i try to assign one image to a contact, then all i can see are gmail contacts instead of my phone contacts. I'm using Jelly bean version. Please help me in this. Phone is Sony xperia C.

Answer (score 0):

Check you 'Contacts' setting: open you 'Contact' -> go to Options -> 'Contact to Display'. See what is checked, setting it to 'Phone' should bring you phone contacts.